# sendKeys to Textbox which you cannot Inspect (using Java)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this alert box with an textbox which cannot be inspected and in want to sendKeys to this textbot.

[inspect absent](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/8/31/c078f992b23d29c2783200dd7236ea2f-full.jpg)

```
public void handleprompt() throws InterruptedException {
    driver.get("http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptprompt.php ");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@onclick='prompter()']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    Alert prompt = driver.switchTo().alert();
    prompt.sendKeys("abcd");
}
```

There is no error but the text is not visible in text box or my code is incorrect

Comment: I don't think you need to use the alert prompt the pop up window looks like the part of the webpage. Paste the html code snippet of the text box that you are trying to sendkeys to. To inspect don't right click on the text box area instead right click area outside and around the text box area.

Answer (score 1):

Hai Bro there is nothing wrong with your code i just simply copy pasted your code and executed it it works absolutely fine

```
public void handleprompt() throws InterruptedException {
    driver.get("http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptprompt.php ");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@onclick='prompter()']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    Alert prompt = driver.switchTo().alert();
    prompt.sendKeys("abcd");
    prompt.Accept();
}
```

After accepting the alert popup you are able to see the text you entered.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the sleep (it's not a good practice) and instead added a wait for the Alert, sendKeys, and then accept. I noticed that I didn't see the text in the alert after sending but when the alert was accepted, it showed the "abcd" text.

```
public void handleprompt() throws InterruptedException {
    String url = "http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptprompt.php";
    driver.get(url);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@onclick='prompter()']")).click();
    Alert prompt = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
    prompt.sendKeys("abcd");
    prompt.accept();
}
```

I tested this code and it's working.